# Passing in a new connection string for a test database

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tdd, nunit, connection-string

I have a asp.net project with a DAL (most code is from someone else but I'm doing maintenance and clean up).

My web application project has a dataprovider class like so:

```
public class DataProvider : IDataProvider
{
     private string DefaultConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public T ExecuteMyQuery<T>(parameters)
    {
          //executes query on db
    }
```

This web application project as has a data layer that interacts between the web pages and the provider like so:

```
public class MyData : IMyData
{
    private readonly IDataProvider dataProvider;

    public MyData(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public string GetTitle(string myVar)
    {
        //builds up stuff to send

         return this.dataProvider.ExecuteMyQuery(...);
     }
 }
```

The connection string for this project is in web.config.

Now I have my tests. For simplicity and time constraints I'm using just a test database and will create the actual objects and test against the test database (in theory we would use more mocks, stubs and all  sorts of stuff but no time.)

So I have a test project which references my web application project above.

```
public class MyTests
{
    private MyData myData;
    private DataProvider dataProvider;

    [SetUp]
    protected void SetUp()
    {
        dataProvider = new DataProvider();
        mysData = new MyData(dataProvider);   
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckTitles()
    {
        string title = myData.GetTitle("AVariable");

        Assert.AreEqual(title, "A typical title");
    }
```

But this keeps give me a null pointer execption when I run it in NUnit.  How do I get my provider to use a new connection string to point to my test database? I tried added an app.config file but it's not working.

Comment: Which line gives the null pointer exception?

Comment: on the return get Connection string

Comment: the connection can't be inherited I guess...so how do I use my web application project's dll but switch and add in a new connection string?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint at `return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]].ConnectionString;`, what is the value of ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Comment: Does your App config have settings for both the connection string and the app setting? Are they called the same as they are in the web config file? Any typos?

Comment: Yeah the app.config I added in and copied the web.config. Not sure why it's not working. The error is null reference (no instance of the object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your app.config (which is copy of web.config) is not loaded as configuration file by default when tests are being run.

I'd prefere to solve that in the following way:

1. Create `IConfiguration` interface which encapsulates details of getting connectionString

   ```
       public interface IConfiguration {
           string MyConnectionString { get; }
       }
   ```
2. Create implementation of `IConfiguration` which reads `web.config` to use it in real code)

   ```
   public class Configuration : IConfiguration
   {
       public string MyConnectionString
       {
           get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]].ConnectionString; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Introduce `IConfiguration` dependency into `DataProvider` class

   ```
   public class DataProvider : IDataProvider
   {
       private IConfiguration configuration;

       public DataProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           this.configuration = configuration;
       }

       private string DefaultConnectionString
       {
           get
           {
               return configuration.MyConnectionString;
           }
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

   Simple refactoring extracts knowledge about reading `web.config` from your `DataProvider` :)
4. In your test use `IConfiguration` stub which returns any connection string what you need for testing. (you can create stub by using mocking framework like moq/rhino-mock or by implementation of `IConfiguration` which does not read app.config)

   ```
   public class MyTests
   {
       private MyData myData;
       private DataProvider dataProvider;
       private IConfiguration configuration;

       [SetUp]
       protected void SetUp()
       {
           // e.g. here stub is created via Moq
           var configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
           configurationMock.SetupGet(x => x.MyConnectionString).Returns("test connection string");
           configuration = configurationMock.Object;

           dataProvider = new DataProvider(configuration);
           mysData = new MyData(dataProvider);   
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

If reading `web.config` is not goal of your tests then that approach is what you need.
As a bonus knowledge about configuration reading goes to separated class :)

Comment: i want it to actually connect to the test database, not the real one though.\

Comment: You can specify any connection string when you define `configuration` stub: `configuration.SetupGet(x => x.MyConnectionString).Returns("testConnectionString")`. Whatever you write instead of `"testConnectionString"` will be used as connection string in tests.

Comment: hmm will it pull the actual data from the db too?

Comment: and do i put the actual connection string in the app.config file?

Comment: you won't need app.config at all for tests.

Comment: The idea here is to use **different** implementations of `IConnection` for web app and for tests: In web application `configuratuion` provides connection string according to web.config. In tests `configuration` provides connection string according to stubbed value and does not use app config at all.

Comment: so it doesn't use real data? i was trying to test it against an actual TEST DB I have with some theoretical data (more of an integration test)

Comment: It uses real DB. But it does not take connection string from app.config. It takes **connection string from stub** to connect **to real test DB**. There is configuration stubbed, DB is not stubbed.

Comment: so copying your code above, the "test connection string" would be the ACTUAL connection string, say "server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20989/discussion-between-alexander-stepaniuk-and-chris)

Comment: one more note, where is the Mock from? NUnit?

Comment: there is some errors with the above code (using Moq), mock can't be converted to IConfiguration

Comment: cool it compiles, but I think I have something else wrong with my code cause I still get: at MyNamespace.DataProvider.get_DefaultConnectionString() NullReferenceException - Object is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh! I was running NUnit config in Debug instead of Release!